# Managed vs unmanaged resource from a class creation viewpoint

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

What I am trying to understand is when I am creating my own classes, how do I know what is a managed vs unmanaged resource so I know if my class needs to provide the ability to clean it up or if GC will eventually do it.  Also, going a little deeper, when I create a .Dispose() method there will be a block for managed resources and a block for unmanaged resources and how do I know which resources should get cleaned up in which block.

I have read many answers about managed vs unmanaged resources in a C# program but most of them are providing the definition with regards to GC cleanup as in "managed resource are cleaned up by GC and unmanaged resources are not".  That doesn't help me because I can't see how GC determines what it will clean up and what it will leave behind.  I also understand that if a class provides a .Dispose() method that my program should execute it.

I have seen answers stating that if I use a WIN32 API, I've created an unmanaged resource.  If I don't call a WIN32 API, does that mean I don't have any unmanaged resources?  I've also stumbled over Marshall.  Does Marshall also create unmanaged resources?  Are there other "keywords / classes" to use to identify that I'm creating unmanaged resources?

Please exclude from your answers anything about "managed resources that are tying up huge amounts of memory".  I understand that it would be nice to give the ability to free up this memory but it is not a requirement as the GC will eventually do it, just not always in a timely manner.

Comment: I would say as a general rule of thumb, if you don't know the answer, you aren't going to be creating unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you are not crossing the boundaries of native and managed codes you don't have to bother about releasing unmanaged resources in your classes.

When you are running your .NET application, the framework allocates a managed slice in the memory for it, where almost everything that you can access from the .NET framework will be stored and tracked by the GC. Everything else falls outside of this slice, left without the sharp eye of the GC.

So for your question about how the GC determines which resources should be collected and which not, the short answer is that it doesn't know anything about unmanaged resources, so it also does not able to collect them.

These worlds - the native and the managed - are separated but they can communicate with eachother and thats what **Marshalling** is for. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/interop-marshaling). With that of course you can create unmanaged resources but that does not mean that you will do every time when you are using it.

It's also a bit extreme to say that every time you are using Win32 APIs you will create native resources that you must release. 
When you use **Platform Invoke** or **C++/CLI wrapper** calls on any native code which creates pointers or anything which should be released by hand in the native world (those of course are not tracked by the GC), you have to release them manually if they are not released already by the native side. But if you use APIs that just works with primitive types then you don't have to release anything.

If you are not using anything from above then there is a good chance that you don't have to prepare your classes for directly release anything unmanaged.

There are types using native resources - you probably already came accross - which are managed wrappers under the hood. They release those resources in their `Dispose` implementation with marshalling.

For example the `FileStream` managed class is holding an unmanaged handle to the given file. The `FileStream` itself is a managed class tracked and collected by the GC, but the unmanaged handle is not, it must be released manually, so if you, the user of the `FileStream` are not calling its `Dispose` method in your code, that handle will remain in the memory leaking until the application exits.

Comment: So I understand what you said but... I'm looking for "if I do "this" (ex. call a WIN32 API), I created an unmanged resource" and I can't find the rules that tell me what "this" is.  Maybe it's just not that black and white.  If I create a class that uses a FileStream, how do I know that I have an unmanged resource in it other than seeing that it has a .Dispose()?  Do I have to look at everything I use see if it has a .Dispose()?  Is there somewhere (compiler output, diagnostics, etc.) that I can see what is unmanaged?  I'm about to give up and just everything is managed and hope for the best.

Comment: It might happen that you are don't even know that you are using a managed wrapper when you are using the FileStream for example, your best bet is just guessing. Usually everything which uses I/O (e.g. file streams, network, database connections etc.) also uses native resources under the hood. There is no much better way than just check that they are implementing the `IDisposable` or not. If so you should call their `Dispose`, to let them release their native resources. Or before using anything that is foreign to you check the documentation first.

Comment: There are some code analysis tools like Resharper which can notify you when you are not disposing something `IDisposable`, but it's hardly depending on the context of the usage. But this only states for the managed wrappers. 

When you are directly using native APIs in your classes you have to check that the native code you are calling is leaving some unreleased memory behind or not.

Comment: For example this: `IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);` is directly allocating 100 bytes in the unmanaged memory and returns with a pointer to it which must be released manually like this: `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointer);`

Comment: The "this" you are referring to which could lead you to the usage of unmanaged resources could be either a Platform Invoke or a c++/CLI wrapper call. For PInvoke [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/platform-invoke-examples) you can find some examples, there you can see that you can't miss that kind of calls with everything else in the .NET framework.